# MySQL - How can I always round up decimals?

Tags: mysql, rounding

For instance I have the following value:

`0.000018`

This is 6 decimal places, but I want to round it up the nearest whole 4th decimal place, so that:

`0.000018 -> 0.0001`

I've played with the round() funcction but if I simply use the round function:

`round(0.000018,4) = 0.0000`

When dealing with decimals for financial purposes, in this case one needs to round up and charge the customer instead of giving them a freebie!  But `round()` will go round up or down depending on value, I need to consistently round up.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: I can't get how you expect round(0.000018) to be 0.0002?

Comment: He doesn't, because round goes up or down. That's why there is a question :)

Comment: Sorry, typo there... I meant 0.0001.  Corrected in original question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [ceil (ceiling)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil). It only rounds up, so you'll have to multiply with 10000, do the ceil and then divide the result again.

So `ceil(0.000145* 10000) = ceil(1.45) = 2`
Divide back and you'll have `0.0002`

EDIT: wait, wut? that doesn't work. I mean `FLOOR` obviously but the working is the same :D
The manual is on the same page too :)

So `floor(0.000145* 10000) = floor(1.45) = 1`
Divide back and you'll have `0.0001`

Comment: Thanks, think ceil() is the answer here:
ceil(0.000001*10000)/10000 = 0.0001              
ceil(0.000011*10000)/10000 = 0.0001              
ceil(0.000111*10000)/10000 = 0.0002              
ceil(0.000200*10000)/10000 = 0.0002              
ceil(0.000201*10000)/10000 = 0.0003

Answer (score 5):

There's another method, which is to add half a multiple of 10. For example: `round(x+0.005, 2)` where x is 0.923 = 0.93 which reduces the maximum floating point division error.

Comment: MySQL's round has quite undefined behavior for inprecise numbers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round (For approximate-value numbers, the result depends on the C library)

Comment: This will work incorrectly when the value is x.00, it will round up to x.01.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROUND(X,D)`, which rounds the value X to D decimal places.

Comment: This does not round up as the OP requested. `ROUND(1.11,1)` will go to `1.1` instead of `1.2`