# Changing decimal places of a Double value MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database table called **druginfo**. It contains prices in **WSprice** column. Type of **WSprice** column is Double. This means It can contain like 23.5698 values. But I want to show all the values in the column **WSprice**   2 decimal places rounded like 23.57. How to apply that to all values in the column? Help me to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705548/mysql-how-can-i-always-round-up-decimals

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format number to 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190668/format-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Why is it DOUBLE??????

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only want to *display* your `DOUBLE` column to 2 decimal places, you can use the `ROUND` function:

```
SELECT ROUND(column_name, 2)
FROM your_table
```

This will display a value of `23.5698` as  `23.57` in the result set.

If you want to *change* the format of the entire column you can use this:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY column_name DECIMAL(9, 2)
```

Comment: I just used an example as 23.5698 But in the column there  are many values like that example @Tim Biegeleisen how to commonly change the decimal places to 2 of all values?

Comment: Do you want to _show_ 2 decimal places, or do you want to _change_ the entire column to be rounded to 2 decimal places?

Comment: I want to change the entire column to be rounded to 2 decimal places. @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: You should change your column to `DECIMAL(9,2)`, which is a fixed point type, unlike float - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html

Comment: And If your old data type is `DOUBLE` and you don't want to change it, just use `DOUBLE(9,2)` like `DECIMAL` this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to use `CAST()` instead of `ROUND()`.

The reason behind is `ROUND()` return decimal values when decimal value exists in the database.

**Example**:

```
SELECT ROUND(columnName, 2)
FROM tableName
```

if columnName = `10.5` Output will be like `10.50`

But if columnName = `10` Output will be like `10`

And `CAST()` will return decimal value. But we need `DECIMAL` with `CAST`

```
SELECT CAST(columnName AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM tableName
```

The output will be like `10.00`