# Mysql - round half down or half up

Tags: mysql, rounding

Is there a way to specify if we want to round a field value 4.485 to 4.48(half down) or to 4.49 (half up) in a sql query with MySql?

Thanks

Comment: Given that target number of decimal places, 4.485 always rounds to 4.48.  Always.  That's how rounding works.  4.485 to 4.48 is [truncating](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-truncate-function.php).

Comment: maybe in mysql always round half down, but in PHP for example it can be defined

Answer (score 3):

Even if the question is years old, I had the same problem and found a different solution I'd like to share.

Here it is: using a conditional function you explicitly decide which way you want to round when the last decimal is 5.
For instance, if you want to round half up with 2 decimals:

```
SELECT IF ((TRUNCATE(mynumber*1000,0) mod 5) = 0,CEIL(mynumber*100)/100,ROUND(mynumber,2)) as value FROM mytable
```

You can use FLOOR function instead of CEIL if you want to round half down; if you want a different number of decimals, say *n*, you change the multiplier inside the TRUNCATE call (10^*n+1*) and you pass it to the ROUND function.

```
SELECT IF ((TRUNCATE(mynumber*([10^*n+1*]),0) mod 5) = 0,[CEIL|FLOOR](mynumber*100)/100,ROUND(mynumber,[*n*])) as value FROM mytable
```

Comment: excellent! exactly what i was after. thanks for sharing!!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the official MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-rounding.html) there is no way to specify a rounding strategy. By default, ROUND uses the “round half up” rule for exact-value numbers.
However, I needed a function that behaves like `java.math.BigDecimal` with `java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN` mode. So the only solution that I found was to create my own function.

### The code (tested in MySQL 5.7)

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS roundHalfDown //
CREATE FUNCTION roundHalfDown (
    numberToRound DECIMAL(25,15),
    roundingPrecision TINYINT(2)
)
    RETURNS DECIMAL(25,15)
BEGIN
    DECLARE digitPosition TINYINT (2) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE digitToRound TINYINT (2) DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE roundedNumber DECIMAL(20,6) DEFAULT 0;

    SET digitPosition = INSTR(numberToRound, '.');

    IF (roundingPrecision < 0) THEN
        SET digitPosition = digitPosition + roundingPrecision;
    ELSE
        SET digitPosition = digitPosition + roundingPrecision + 1;
    END IF;

    IF (digitPosition > 0
        AND digitPosition <= CHAR_LENGTH(numberToRound)
    ) THEN
        
        SET digitToRound = CAST(
                SUBSTR(
                numberToRound, 
                digitPosition, 
                1
            ) AS UNSIGNED
        );

        SET digitPosition = digitPosition - 1;
    END IF;

    IF (digitToRound > -1) THEN

        IF (digitToRound > 5) THEN

            SET roundedNumber = ROUND(numberToRound, roundingPrecision);
        ELSEIF (digitToRound = 5 AND CAST(
                SUBSTR(
                REPLACE(numberToRound, '.', ''), 
                digitPosition + 1
            ) AS UNSIGNED) > 0) THEN
            SET roundedNumber = ROUND(numberToRound, roundingPrecision);
        ELSE
            SET roundedNumber = TRUNCATE(numberToRound, roundingPrecision);
        END IF;

    ELSEIF (roundingPrecision > 0) THEN
        SET roundedNumber = numberToRound;
    END IF;

    RETURN roundedNumber;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

### Test Cases

```
SELECT roundHalfDown(1.541, 2); #1.54
SELECT roundHalfDown(1.545, 2); #1.54
SELECT roundHalfDown(1.5451, 2); #1.55
SELECT roundHalfDown(1.54500001, 2); #1.55
SELECT roundHalfDown(1.54499999, 2); #1.54
SELECT roundHalfDown(-1.545, 2); #-1.54
SELECT roundHalfDown(-1.5451, 2); #-1.55
SELECT roundHalfDown(555, 0); #555
SELECT roundHalfDown(1000999, -1); #1001000
SELECT roundHalfDown(1000999, -2); #1001000
SELECT roundHalfDown(1000999, -3); #1001000
SELECT roundHalfDown(1000999, -4); #1000000
```

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36843809/10239149) from another Stack Overflow question, but I changed it a bit for my specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Andrea Pegoretti's answer is almost correct, however it will apply when it's a 5 or a 0 instead of just a 5.

My fix (for round down):

```
SELECT IF (SUBSTR(TRUNCATE(CEIL(mynumber*1000),0),-1) = 5,FLOOR(mynumber*100)/100,ROUND(mynumber, 2))) AS value FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer of this post offers a good solution :
[MySQL - How can I always round up decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705548/mysql-how-can-i-always-round-up-decimals)

i.e multiply by 10^n where n is the decimal place you want to round to then call `ceil` to round up or `floor` to round down and divide by 10^n.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CEIL (or CEILING) and the FLOOR functions to round up/round down.

For example:

```
CEIL(4.485 * 100) / 100 will return 4.49
FLOOR(4.485 * 100) / 100 will return 4.48
```

Comment: it is true, but the question was that if its possible to define mysql behaviour to round half up or down. meaning: 1.5 half down = 1, 1,5 half up = 2, CEIL will round up 4.4 also to 5 which is not the right answer here

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question and I try all kind of custom function to emulate the functionality of PHP with a round up and down, but after a while, I figured out that MySQL produces different results using float and doubles fields.

Here my test.

```
mysql> describe test_redondeo;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| columna_double | double(15,3) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| columna_float  | float(9,3)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

In fields type double, round function truncate, but in float round up.

```
mysql> select columna_double, columna_float, round ( columna_double, 2) as round_double, round ( columna_float, 2) as round_float from test_redondeo;
+----------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
| columna_double | columna_float | round_double | round_float |
+----------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
|        902.025 |       902.025 |       902.02 |      902.03 |
+----------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you made a custom function for round a number using round() in any way, please pay attention to type of field.

Hope this test helps you.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-rounding.html),

- For **exact-value numbers**, ROUND() uses the “round half up” rule

I had also a situation, where I was wondering why is Mysql rounding(1) 74,447 to 74,4. It was because it was in fact an endless long decimal, a **approximate-value number**, and not a **exact-value number**. The solution for me was, that I had to use `ROUND()` 3x like this: `ROUND(ROUND(ROUND(value, 3), 2), 1)`. The first rounding makes sure that it's not a **approximate-value number** any more (where Mysql uses the “round to nearest even” rule), but a **exact-value number**, a decimal 3 number.

Comment: 74.447 should round to 74.4 as 74.447 is less than 74.5?

Comment: Nope. 74,447 should be rounded to 74,5 in two steps, first to 74,45 and that to 74,5. It's basic math.

Comment: But why are you rounding in steps? If you have If you're doing `ROUND(ROUND(ROUND(74.447, 3), 2), 1)` then yes - that's 74.5 but `ROUND(74.447, 1)` is the same as `ROUND(74.44, 1)`, which is `74.4`.

Comment: It's not the same and mathematically incorrect. Why MySql is doing it like this I have no idea. I just know that I have to round in two steps in order to get mathematically correct results. But if you can live with the normal behaviour, I'm happy for you. Ask a mathematician or a maths teacher if 74,447 should be rounded normally to 74,45 or 74,44. Or are you a maths teacher?

Comment: 74.447 should round to 74.45 if rounded to two decimal places but 74.4 if rounded to 1. 74.45 should round to 74.5. When rounding you only look at one less significant figure, whatever comes after that is irrelevant so for rounding purposes (to one decimal place) 74.447 is just 74.44 - the 7 at the end does not come into it. You could have 74.449999999999999 and it would still be 74.4 to 1 decimal place

Comment: "74.447 should round to ... 74.4 if rounded to 1." - unfortunately not. You cannot skip the 2nd decimal. You round to 74.45 first, and than round to 74.5. You always have to round each decimal. According to math rules. A decimal of 5 is always rounding up.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, you are right.