# How to round 4600 to 4500 and 4450 to 4000 in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How to round 4600 to 4500 and 4450 to 4000 in mysql?

try:
``` ROUND((``price``,-3),TRUNCATE(``price``,-2.5) ```

example:

`13650` To `13500` and `20475` To `20000`

Comment: This is basic arithmetic.

Comment: what?not clear.

Comment: `SELECT FLOOR(13650/500)*500 n;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843808/mysql-round-half