# Round sum of decimal columns in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum, rounding

I am using this code for sum/addition and to multiply two values of database AMOUNT & RATE.

```
SELECT YEAR, COST, RATE, SUM(AMOUNT) AS ONE, ROUND(SUM(AMOUNT*RATE/100),0) AS COST 
FROM DATABASE 
WHERE YEAR='$YEAR'
```

But round value is not working

```
650 x 5 / 100 = 32  instead of 33
720 x 8 / 100 = 57  instead of 58
```

Total of COST is coming to 89 instead of 91 as i need total of round value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - How can I always round up decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705548/mysql-how-can-i-always-round-up-decimals)

Comment: You have a table called database?

Comment: NO ceil function not work in fetching data from sql

Comment: NO my database name is TAX2021

Comment: `SELECT ROUND(650*5/100,0);` returns 33. Cannot reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently round the sum, not the summands. Round the summands. (And use `ceil()` instead of `round()`, if you always want the minimal greater or equal integer, not "true" rounding.)

```
SELECT year,
       cost,
       rate,
       sum(amount) one,
       sum(round(amount * rate / 100, 0)) cost 
       FROM `database`
       WHERE year = ?
       GROUP BY year,
                cost,
                rate;
```

Some notes:

- Your query was malformed in general. There were columns in the list of selected columns that neither were in the `GROUP BY` clause nor an argument to an aggregation function. Sadly old MySQL versions or badly configured ones accept such erroneous queries. But the result can suddenly be funny.
- Do not use string interpolation or concatenation to get values into SQL queries. That's error prone and might make your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries. See ["How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement) and ["How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
- `database` is a really bad table name.